# How do you refer to someone in a formal essay?

Tags: characters, non-fiction, essay, mla, biography

I'm writing a formal essay on a book. The book is about a real person, but they are referred to by their first name throughout the entire book. When writing the essay, do I stay consistent with the book and refer to the person by their first name, or go the formal essay route and call them by their last name?

Comment: Are you supposed to apply a particular style guide?

Comment: Not that I know of. The only description of the style was just "formal essay", so I'm assuming MLA and not using first person. That's kind of all I've got.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [MLA website](https://style.mla.org/using-last-name-only/), you should give the person's full name and then refer to them by their last name thereafter.